# How to Create Presentation Slides with 200 page HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hope everyone can help me, I'm having difficulty & tired of creating sliders with over 200 slides in html & CSS.

I want to creat slides with 200 slide html & css

index.html

css/style.css

js/scripts.js

img/

slides/

- 1.html & 1.css
- 2.html & 2.css
- 3.html & 3.css

......

- 200.html & 200.css

My index

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <title>Slider Page Simulator</title>
</head>
 <style>
 
 </style>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
   <div id="slides">
      <!-- load in slides -->
   </div>
</div>  
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="./js/mysliders.js"></script>
</html>
```

My Jquery

```html
var Slides = {
   container : $('#slides'),
 
   totalSlides : '',
 
   translateAmount : 0,
 
   currentSlide : 0,
 
   slideWidth : '',
 
   init : function(totalSlides) {
      var each;
 
      if ( !totalSlides ) throw new Error('Please pass the total number of slides.');
      Slides.totalSlides = totalSlides;
 
      Slides.loadContent();
 
      each = Slides.container.children('div');
       
      // Determine the width of our canvas
      Slides.slideWidth = each.width() + ( parseInt( each.css('margin-right'), 10 ) );
 
      Slides.keyPress();
   },
 
   loadContent : function() {
      Slides.container.hide();
      for ( var i = 0; i < Slides.totalSlides; i++ ) {
         $('<div id="#slide-' + i + '"></div>')
            .load('.slides/' + i + '.html')
            .appendTo(Slides.container);
         }
      Slides.container.show();
   },
 
   keyPress : function() {
      $(document.body).keydown(function(e) {
         // if left or right arrow key is pressed
         if ( e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ( e.keyCode === 39 ) ? Slides.next() : Slides.prev();
         }
      });
   },
 
   next : function( ) {
      Slides.translateAmount -= Slides.slideWidth;
      Slides.updateHash( ++Slides.currentSlide );
      Slides.animate();
   },
 
  prev : function() {
     // No more left to go back.
      if ( Slides.translateAmount === 0 ) return;
 
      Slides.translateAmount += Slides.slideWidth;
      Slides.updateHash( --Slides.currentSlide );
      Slides.animate();
  },
 
  animate : function() {
     Slides
      .container
      .children()
         .css( '-webkit-transform', 'translateX(' + Slides.translateAmount + 'px)' );
  },
 
  updateHash : function( direction ) {
     // Update current Slides and hash.
     location.hash = '#slide-' + Slides.currentSlide;
  }
};
 
// All right; let's do this. 
Slides.init(6);
```

Thank you so much

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: i think you should use https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js for slider , real demo is here : https://revealjs.com/#/ as i dont get your problem also

Comment: I came across reveal.js, I did not want to use sections for each slide, I want to use html & css of page html